# Appending <a> and <img> to document.body removes href and src

Tags: javascript, html

So, I'm creating an article block like this:

```
<article>
    <figure>
        <img src="source" />
    </figure>
    <div>
        <a href="link"/>
    </div>
</article>
```

This is my js code:

```
var linkElement = document.createElement('a');
var linkText = document.createTextNode(*some text*);
linkElement.appendChild(linkText);
linkElement.href = *link*;

var imgElement = document.createElement('img');
imgElement.setAttribute("src", *some path*);
imgElement.setAttribute("width", "304");
imgElement.setAttribute("height", "228");
imgElement.setAttribute("alt", temp["name"]);

var article = document.createElement("article"),
    figure = document.createElement("figure"),
    div = document.createElement("div");

div.appendChild(linkElement);
figure.appendChild(imgElement);
article.appendChild(figure);
article.appendChild(div);

document.querySelector('article').appendChild(article);
```

This is my html code:

```
<body>

     <header></header>

     <section>
         <article></article>
     </section>

     <footer></footer>

    <script src = *src of my js*></script>

</body>
```

If I create one article block, everything is fine. The problem arises when I create an array of article blocks. Every block except the last one loses its href and src for the 'a' and 'img'tags. An empty image box appears and the text without the link appears. Can anyone explain why it happens and how I can change that?

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BY3ts.png) 
I printing a list of FB movie pages with their picture and links to the page.

My original code:

```
// data has a list of FB movie pages, each containing the name of t he movie and page id
function print(data)
{
//iterates through the object passed to print movie names in console.  

var target = document.querySelector('article');
var docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        var temp = data[i];
        var linkElement = document.createElement('a');
        var linkText = document.createTextNode(temp["name"]);
        linkElement.appendChild(linkText);
        //getting the link to the movie's FB page
        getLink(function(response){linkElement.href = response;},temp["id"]);

        var imgElement = document.createElement('img');
        //getting the src of the picture of the movie's page
        getPic(function(response){imgElement.setAttribute("src", response);},temp["id"]);
        imgElement.setAttribute("width", "304");
        imgElement.setAttribute("height", "228");
        imgElement.setAttribute("alt", temp["name"]);

        var article = document.createElement("article"),
            figure = document.createElement("figure"),
            div = document.createElement("div");

        div.appendChild(linkElement);
        figure.appendChild(imgElement);
        article.appendChild(figure);
        article.appendChild(div);
        console.log(article);
        docFrag.appendChild(article);
    }
    target.appendChild(docFrag);
}

function getLink(callback,id)
{
   FB.api('/'+id+'?fields=link', function(response)
   {
       callback(response.link);
   });
}
function getPic(callback,id)
{
   FB.api('/'+id+'?fields=cover{source}', function(response)
       {
      callback(response.cover.source);
  });
}
```

Comment: How are you creating the array? Show the code with problem.

Comment: I missed the part when you actually append article to body...hmm? Or `.boxes`

Comment: @zer00ne Sorry, my mistake. This is the line: document.querySelector('article').appendChild(linkElement);

Comment: @acdcjunior I thought appending the article to the document.body created a sort-of array. That's what I meant.

Comment: *The problem arises when I create an array of article blocks* - your code does not do that, so, you're probably doing that wrong

Comment: @JithinJacob what sort of syntax is: `*link*`? asterisks instead of quotes? Anyways see my answer which uses arrays for unique values but uses a loop to generate the generic elements. Note that the actual manipulation of the DOM is done only once.

Comment: `document.querySelector('article').appendChild(linkElement); ` is not possible because this was already done: `div.appendChild(linkElement);`. Even if that was possible, then you'd have a link in the DOM but you still have the `<img>` and `<figure>` attached to an `<article>` that is still floating around never being appended to the DOM.

Comment: @zer00ne I'm sorry again. the line was supposed to be      document.querySelector('article').appendChild(article);

Comment: @JithinJacob That should work I guess, the problem isn't really fresh in my head anymore. Do you have any problems with my answer?

Comment: Note that the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has.

Comment: I'm creating the img block dynamicall. So the slash won't be a part of the code. It was a typo. I'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

If just going by the OP code, it never appends anything to the DOM. The `<article>` is created and everything is appended to it but it never finds its way to the DOM.

Once that is taken care of you must be mindful of the urls assigned to your images. They will fail should you mix secured content with unsecured content.

**Secured Content:**

```
<img src='https://....>
```

**Unsecured Content:**

```
<img src='http://....>?
```

BTW, this Demo is reusable and easily expandable. The simple requirement is that for each `<article>` you must add an appropriate url to the `url[]` and `posters[]` arrays. Also the layout is streamlined: `<img>` is nested with `<a>` and `<a>` is nested within `<fig>`, and `<fig>` is nested within `<article>`. This arrangement makes the entire `<img>` a link.

### Demo

**Details commented in Demo and references are located below the Demo**

```js
// Array of urls to sites for lnk.href
var urls = ['https://www.starwars.com', 'https://www.marvel.com'];

// Array of urls to images for img.src
var posters = ["https://imgc.allpostersimages.com/img/print/u-g-F93H7K0.jpg?w=900&h=900&p=0", "https://imgc.allpostersimages.com/img/print/u-g-F90CQI0.jpg?w=900&h=900&p=0"];

// Reference the DOM target
var target = document.querySelector('.action');

/* Create a DocumentFragment Object to add all of your articles
|| to. The only thing you should ever append to the DOM is the
|| docFrag. It's costly to add to DOM so do it only once.
*/
var docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();

/* One loop will:
|| - create the 4 components: article, figure, a, img
|| - get the urls from the 2 arrays and assign them to 
||   lnk.href and img.src
|| - set the additional attributes to img
|| - append components: img to a--a to fig--fig to art--art to 
||   docFrag--docFrag to target(a section attached to the DOM)
*/
/* This `for` loop will go 2 times because the .length of urls[]
|| array is 2 (note: i < urls.length)
 */
for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
  var art = document.createElement('article');
  var fig = document.createElement('figure');
  var lnk = document.createElement('a');
  lnk.href = urls[i];
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = posters[i];
  img.width = '200';
  img.height = '300';

  lnk.appendChild(img);
  fig.appendChild(lnk);
  art.appendChild(fig);
  docFrag.appendChild(art);
}

target.appendChild(docFrag);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
</head>

<body>

  <header></header>
  <main>
    <section class="action"></section>
  </main>
  <footer></footer>


</body>

</html>
```

### Reference

[**What is the DOM?**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction)

[**DocumentFragment**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment)

Comment: I think my code is correct. But I'm getting the links and img sources from the FB SDK which makes use of asynchronous calls. So, when I try to assign the links and the sources to variables, it's getting assigned null values before function returns the required values. I think I should start a new thread for this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Since it's correct (but doesn't work) can you please explain this part: `linkElement.href = *link*;` ? and you had said: *"I thought appending the article to the document.body created a sort-of array. "* That makes very little sense.  Is `*link*` syntax from FB SDK?

Comment: I meant *link* as in *some link* like I did for the line above in createTextNode(*some text*).

Comment: And by the sort-of array, I meant that since we're appending newly created articles to the DOM, it was analogous to appending elements to an array